# How do I get the size of a maximized window without showing it?

Tags: c, gtk, gobject

I am trying to determine the size of a maximized window so I can set the window size to a value close to it. However, I don't know how to do that without first showing the maximized window. Is there a way to emit the signal generated by gtk_window_maximize before the window is displayed?

Below is my attempt so far. The problem is that I can see a flash of the maximized window before the resizing takes place.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int signal_id;

void resize(GtkWindow *window, GdkEvent *event, gpointer data)
{
    gint width, height;

    g_signal_handler_disconnect(G_OBJECT(window), signal_id);
    gtk_window_get_size(window, &width, &height);
    gtk_window_resize(window, width - 10, height - 10);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GtkWidget *window;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    signal_id = g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(window), "configure-event", G_CALLBACK(resize), NULL);
    gtk_window_maximize(GTK_WINDOW(window));
    gtk_widget_show_all(GTK_WIDGET(window));

    gtk_main();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not possible, because until the window manager maps the window, the actual size is not known. But what you can do is get the screen size:

```
width=gdk_screen_width();
height=gdk_screen_height();
gtk_widget_set_size_request(window, width/2, height/2);
```

Comment: OK, so there is now way to get the WM to map an invisible window, right? What I really would like to do is to make the window almost as large as a maximized one (i have edited my post to reflect this).

Comment: Then just set the window to be 0.8 * screen width and 0.8 * screen height for example. And if you use gtk_widget_set_size_request() it should set the size when it maps it.

Comment: The other thing to be careful of is that the window contents don't force the window to expand. To get around this, put all of the window contents inside a scrolled window inside the main window.

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom: Additionally `gtk_window_maximize` is only a request to the window manager which it can happily choose to ignore. This is mentioned in the documentation as well. The suggested method maybe a good idea ... but then again the maximum screen size may not be the size of the maximized window